# Page headers for sections in a Google doc

Tags: google-docs, headers

I want to use different page headers for each section of a Google doc.  When I edit a page header, the Options menu offers Whole document, This section, and From this point forward.  No matter which I choose, my header gets applied to the entire document.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs does **not** support custom headers per page. If you double-click the header area you can trigger to have a custom header of the first page **only**. For the rest of your document, a global header shall be applied per every page other than the 1st one.

[image]